# VB.NET rounding from 0 to 4 -->0 from 5 to 9 --> 1

Tags: vb.net, rounding

We need to apply two rounding as the below rules:

if the 3rd number is between 0 and 4 --> +0
if the 3rd number is between 5 and 9 --> +1

I have tried the below but is not what we need

```vb
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("142.5700 --> " & Math.Round(142.5700,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven))
        Console.WriteLine("142.5710 --> " & Math.Round(142.5710,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven))
        Console.WriteLine("142.5720 --> " & Math.Round(142.5720,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven))
        Console.WriteLine("142.5730 --> " & Math.Round(142.5730,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven))
        Console.WriteLine("142.5740 --> " & Math.Round(142.5740,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven))
        Console.WriteLine("142.5750 --> " & Math.Round(142.5750,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven))
        Console.WriteLine("142.5760 --> " & Math.Round(142.5760,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven))
        Console.WriteLine("142.5770 --> " & Math.Round(142.5770,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven))
        Console.WriteLine("142.5780 --> " & Math.Round(142.5780,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven))
        Console.WriteLine("142.5790 --> " & Math.Round(142.5790,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven))
    End Sub
End Module
```

```
142.5700 --> 142.57
142.5710 --> 142.57
142.5720 --> 142.57
142.5730 --> 142.57
142.5740 --> 142.57
142.5750 --> 142.57  this is wrong we need to have 142.58
142.5760 --> 142.58
142.5770 --> 142.58
142.5780 --> 142.58
142.5790 --> 142.58
```

i try to fix my below code ... but i still not take the correct output

'''
Public Function calculateTax (gameId As String, multiplier As String, CSWinning As String) As String
CSWinning = CSWinning.Replace(".",",")
Dim wins As Decimal = 0
Dim firstTax As Decimal = CDec(0.15)
Dim secondTax As Decimal = CDec(0.2)

```
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(multiplier) OrElse multiplier.Equals("0") Then
        multiplier = "1"
    End If
    
    Dim winningsMinuscolumns As String = ((CDec(CSWinning) - getColumnCostByGame(gameId)) *CDec(multiplier.Replace("[","").Replace("]",""))).ToString
    
    'Check initially if winning sum is smaller than 100 
    If CDec(winningsMinuscolumns) <= CDec(100) Then
        wins = CDec(CSWinning)
        'Check initially if winning sum is smaller than 500 
    Else If CDec(winningsMinuscolumns) <= CDec(500)
        Dim taxedSum As Decimal = CDec(winningsMinuscolumns) - CDec(100)
        wins = CDec(CDec(CSWinning) - 100) - CDec(taxedSum * firstTax)
        wins = wins + CDec(100)
        'Check initially if winning sum is larger than 500 
    Else
        Dim taxedSum As Decimal = CDec(winningsMinuscolumns) - CDec(500)
        wins = CDec(CDec(CSWinning) - 500) - CDec(taxedSum * secondTax)
        wins = (CDec(400) - (CDec(400) * firstTax)) + wins
        wins = wins + CDec(100)
    End If
    Report.Info("BeforeRound  " & (wins))
    Report.Info("AfterRound  " & roundEven(wins))
    
    Return (roundEven(wins) * CDec(multiplier.Replace("[","").Replace("]",""))).ToString
End Function

    Public Function roundEven(num As Decimal) As Double
    Report.Info("Inside   " & num)
    Report.Info("Inside  cdbl " & CDbl(num))
    Return Math.Round(CDbl(num),2,MidpointRounding.ToEven)
    
End Function
```

'''
00:14.902 Info User BeforeRound 142,5750
00:14.932 Info User Inside 142,5750
00:14.961 Info User Inside cdbl 142,575
00:14.994 Info User AfterRound 142,57
'''

Comment: It's because you are [using `double`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/11683). With `decimal`s, `142.5750` is rounded to `142.58`. [Add `@`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters) to your numeric literals. You also appear to want `AwayFromZero`, not `ToEven`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is using floating point numbers which means `142.575` isn't quite `142.575` due to scaling errors. If you try to print the number with more than 13 fractional digits, eg:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:N14}",142.575)
```

You'll get

```
142.57499999999999
```

If you use a decimal literal though, you'll get the expected result. The following line :

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:N24}",142.575D)
```

produces

```
142.575000000000000000000000
```

and

```
Math.Round(142.575D,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven)
```

produces

```
142.58
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use Math.round(142.575D,2,MidpointRounting)

output will be 142.58

Answer (score 0):

Try using .AwayFromZero instead of .ToEven.  This uses Double.

```
    For d As Double = 142.57# To 142.58# Step 0.001#
        Console.WriteLine("{0:n4} --> {1}", d, Math.Round(d, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
    Next
```

The real question is what do the numbers represent(i.e. money or scientific calculation)? If this is monetary use Decimal.  If scientific use double.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the original strings and formatted them to 2 decimal places.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim lst As New List(Of String) From {"142.5700", "142.5710", "142.5720", "142.5730", "142.5740", "142.5750", "142.5760", "142.5770", "142.5780", "142.5790"}
    For Each s In lst
        Console.WriteLine($"{s}--->{CDbl(s):N2}")
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```